# Как посылать event слушателю вручную

Tags: java, swing

Есть массив кнопок, к которым регистрируется обработчик со сложной логикой

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            MyButton b = new MyButton();
            b.setBackground(Color.white);
            b.setLocation(i, j);
            b.addActionListener(CellListener.getInstance());
            b.setBounds(40+j*20, 40+i*20, 20, 20);
            this.add(b);
            arrayCell.add(b);
        }
    }
```

Как можно принудительно из другого места программы генерировать события на этих кнопках для тестирования логики прикрепленного слушателя?

Comment: Судя по [en-SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5109301/3212712) вам нужен `doClick()`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  Спасибо! всё заработало

Comment: @ЮрийСПб может как ответ оформите свой комментарий?)

Comment: @Denis, а это и был ответ) Просто его система сама в коммент переделала как слишком короткий(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5109301/3212712) вам нужен метод `doClick()`, который как раз и сделает программное нажатие на кнопку